# How to run Timer Task with dynamic changeable time?

Tags: java

We know that we can run call a method after some specific interval of time.  For instance:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new MyClass(), 0, 5000);

class MyClass extends TimerTask {

    public void run() {
        // logic
    }
}
```

Everything seems ok! But how can I specify random time every time? In the other words, I do not want to invoke method every N milliseconds,  but I need to invoke it with random delay interval every time.

For example delay to be in the range of [M-N], if M=5000 and N=20000 then:

- 1th delay: random number from range  [5000-20000]
- 2th dalay: random    number from range  [5000-20000]

end etc...

I'm finding easiest way (library) to implement. It can be another class. I cant find if Timer have this functionality.

Best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is

```
public void schedule() {
    timer.schedule(new MyClass(),Math.round(Math.random()*15000)+5000);
}
class MyClass extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {

    //your code

    //schedule next task;
     schedule();
    }
}
```

Comment: Would this randomize the time every time the method `run` is called or would he have to re-instantiate the `timer`?

Comment: It is creating a new TimerTask every time, but you can reuse the same Timer.